# get dialog with html and script from using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, browser-cache

when a user open a new dialog in my application.
i am getting the dialog HTML and script who are responsible to handle that dialog.
when i am opening the same dialog again.

seems like the browser is caching my javascript from the previous dialog.
so for some cases i have scripts who are running twice.

example of i am doing :

```
var html = $.get('/somepage');
dialog.empty().append(html);
dialog.dialog("open");
```

how can i overcome that ?

here is an example that will help explain the problem

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script id="myscript">var seachForMe = 1;</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready( function(){
        $("#clickme").click(function() {
            $("#centent").empty().append($("<span>some text </span>")).append($("#myscript").clone());
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="centent"></div>
<input type="button" id="clickme" value="click me again and again">
</body>
</html>
```

i am using clone, since it will be a new script returning from the server 
i am empty the content div but still the script is in the browser .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
   var html = $.ajax({
        url: '/somepage',
        cache: false,
        type: GET
    });
```

That is if your problem is really with the cache.

Comment: when searching for the script using firebug, i see my script twice when i open the dialog again...

Comment: Your problem is probably not the cache and you should make a jsFiddle if you want more help. http://jsfiddle.com/

Comment: jsFiddle don't like the idea of dynamically creating scripts. but i will paste a code snippet to my question

Comment: i can find any global ajax that will bring script along, and the cache flag is not helping .

Comment: Add more code to your question then. I can't help with what I can't see.

Comment: facebook 'primer' JS API doing something similar getting the JS for the dialog alone. i like this approach but then this problem came along,just want to clear the JS when i am emptying my dialog

Comment: So do you want to put the things from inside `#myscript` into `#centent`? Or the actual `#myscript` element?

Comment: i have a jquery ui dialog,for lots of actions, each ajax replace this dialog content. each content comes with JS, just want to clear the JS with the HTML that inside the dialog ,"myscript" its just an example for a same cloned script

Comment: So look at this http://jsfiddle.net/jonnysooter/kQ2cT/1/ it removes the script from the page and adds the html to the div.

Comment: the script coming back from the server should run and manage html content that came with it. when emptying the dialog and calling the same ajax , i get the same script again , but the new script and the previous scring are still in memory <div>some html</div><script>manage the some html</script>. now remove this when dialog closed and call it again , i have the manage code twice

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34256/discussion-between-jonny-sooter-and-shay-te)

Comment: remember i am getting the dialog content using ajax.

Comment: Go to this chat so we can talk easier - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34256/discussion-between-jonny-sooter-and-shay-te